# Text autopopulating in input text even when AutoComplete is OFF

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

[image: Screenshot]
As the image explains, I have put `autocomplete='off'` on the input, however Firefox is still populating the saved username.

Comment: You may be seeing a cached page. Try Ctrl+F5 to fully refresh the page.

Comment: [Disable Firefox's Auto-fill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487970/disable-firefoxs-auto-fill)

Comment: Thats fine, I can disable firefox's autofill but can I specifically force any input field not to autofill even if FF's autofill is enabled?

Comment: Hey, I got a solution for this!
put a hidden empty text field after the password or email type input field and it rocks!

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this! put a hidden empty text field after the password or email type input field and it rocks!

Autocomplete has been disabled for password type input fields. The above links mention that respectively for FireFox and IE, but I see that setting autocomplete to off for form too is not working

Use below code
`<input name="test" type="text" style="display:none">`

Comment: <input name="test" type="text" style="display:none">